# Missing duplicate banner on specific question

Tags: support

I found this question:

[Is it better to use #defines, enumeration values or const ints to define constant values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497084/is-it-better-to-use-defines-enumeration-values-or-const-ints-to-define-constan)

which is duplicate of another question, but cannot see the duplicate banner at top (link to duplicate question), is it normal?

screen capture:

[image]

Comment: The post dates from the time when the duplicate banner was edited into the post. Someone else edited it out again (pretty much immediately after the post was closed). I rolled back that edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would it be better to remove the manual banner and re-close it as a duplicate to keep the UI consistent?

Comment: @Rob: meh, too many such posts to bother.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, just took a look; about 20 thousand of them. Fortunately though, there aren't too many with missing banners

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there's about 168 cases of this happening. Not too many to fix up manually. I'll slowly be going through the C# questions to fix the banners, but if anyone else would like to chip in, the following query will grab you the relevant questions in a tag:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/689390

Comment: Yes, please do it slowly. Closure still counts as recent activity on the question, bumping it up to the top. Meta-tasks like this make the home page ("interesting") completely unusable for me.